# Preparing JSON array of Objects from multiple array list

Tags: json, groovy, jsonslurper, jsonbuilder

I am very new to the Groovy scripts and would like to build a JSON output from the below JSON input. Kindly help!

My JSON input looks like this:

```
{
  "id":"1222",
  "storageNode": {
    "uuid": "22255566336",
    "properties": {
      "BuinessUnit": [
        "Light",
        "Fan",
        "Watch"
        ],
      "Contact": [
        "abc@gmail.com",
        "fhh@gmail.com"
        ],
      "Location": [
        "Banglore",
        "Surat",
        "Pune"
        ]
    }
  }
}
```

Expected Output:

```
[
{
  "BuinessUnit": "Light",
  "Contact": "abc@gmail.com",
  "Location": "Banglore"
},
{
  "BuinessUnit": "Fan",
  "Contact": "fhh@gmail.com",
  "Location": "Surat"
},
{
  "BuinessUnit": "Watch",
  "Contact": "",
  "Location": "Pune"
}
]
```

Please note that in case any array is not matching the value count that will always be the last one and in that case, a blank value (**""**) has to be populated. The "**BusinessUnit**" object can be referred for array size validation.

My code looks like this:

```
import com.sap.gateway.ip.core.customdev.util.Message;
import java.util.HashMap;
import groovy.json.*;


def Message processData(Message message) {    
    //Body 
    def body = message.getBody(String.class);    
    def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
    def list = jsonSlurper.parseText(body)
    String temp


    def BU = list.storageNode.properties.get("BusinessUnit")

    def builder = new JsonBuilder(
        BU.collect {
            [
                BusinessUnit: it
                
            ]
        }
    )
    message.setBody(builder.toPrettyString())
    return message
}
```

It is only returning this:

```
[
    {
        "BusinessUnit": "Light"
    },
    {
        "BusinessUnit": "Fan"
    },
    {
        "BusinessUnit": "Watch"
    }
]
```

Now how will I add other parts to it? Please help!

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: Hi Andrej - Thank you for your response. I have updated the post with my code which is a very basic one with the output I am getting. Kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with the following solution that converts source JSON string to the target JSON string:

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def json = '''
{
  "id":"1222",
  "storageNode": {
    "uuid": "22255566336",
    "properties": {
      "BusinessUnit": [
        "Light",
        "Fan",
        "Watch"
        ],
      "Contact": [
        "abc@gmail.com",
        "fhh@gmail.com"
        ],
      "Location": [
        "Banglore",
        "Surat",
        "Pune"
        ]
    }
  }
}
'''

println convert(json)

String convert(String json) {
    def list = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
    List<String> units = list.storageNode.properties.BusinessUnit
    List<String> contacts = list.storageNode.properties.Contact
    List<String> locations = list.storageNode.properties.Location
    def result = []
    units.eachWithIndex { unit, int index ->
        result << [
            BusinessUnit: unit,
            Contact     : contacts.size() > index ? contacts[index] : '',
            Location    : locations.size() > index ? locations[index] : '',
        ]
    }
    return new JsonBuilder(result).toPrettyString()
}
```

I've omitted the logic of getting string from the message and packaging transformed JSON into message.
I hope it will help you to move forward. Please let me know if you need further assistance here.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Andrej for the code. It has worked. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in Groovy facilities, like `transpose()`:

```
import groovy.json.*

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText '''{   "id":"1222",   "storageNode": {     "uuid": "22255566336",     "properties": {       
   "BuinessUnit": [         "Light",         "Fan",         "Watch"         ],      
   "Contact": [         "abc@gmail.com",         "fhh@gmail.com"         ],       
   "Location": [         "Banglore",         "Surat",         "Pune"         ]     }   } }'''

def names = json.storageNode.properties*.key
def values = json.storageNode.properties*.value

int maxSize = values*.size().max()
// pad lists with trainiling spaces
values.each{ v -> ( maxSize - v.size() ).times{ v << '' } }

def result = values.transpose().collect{ tuple -> [ names, tuple ].transpose().collectEntries{ it } }

assert result.toString() == '[[BuinessUnit:Light, Contact:abc@gmail.com, Location:Banglore], [BuinessUnit:Fan, Contact:fhh@gmail.com, Location:Surat], [BuinessUnit:Watch, Contact:, Location:Pune]]'
```

This piece of code can process everything under `storageNode.properties`.